# fetching files in svn after you've skipped them with --depth

Tags: svn

Following another question here, i checked out a copy using --depth to ignore the multi gigabity old branchs, but now i'm having some trouble getting the files i do want.

my project tree:

```
./
|-- proj 1
|    |-- branches
|    `-- trunk
|-- proj 2
|    |-- branches
|    `-- trunk
`-- proj 3
     |-- sub proj A
     |   |-- branches
     |   |-- trunk
     |-- sub proj B
     |   |-- branches
     |   |-- trunk
    ...
```

so, what i did:
`svn checkout $url /workingcopy --depth empty`

then:
`for $f in /workingcopy/*; do svn up "$f/trunk"; done`

now, what i hopped would work:
`cd /workingcopy/proj3; svn up --depth empty`

but instead of fetching the subproj dirs, it just exit saying "revision x"

**how can i fetch all the files/dirs in a directory that is empty because if was checkedout/updated with --depth?**

update: forgot to mention, `svn up proj3/subprojA --depth empty;` does work. but I have a couple dozen files like that... looking for something that will fetch them all like a checkout

Comment: First of all I don't understand how you got `proj 3` directory in the working copy. Secondly, what exactly you are trying to get -- all the directories/files of the `proj 3` subtree or only part of them?

Comment: @Paker, what do you mean? just add the dirs there and commit. then check them out. i got them empty using the --depth argument.  What I want is to get all the trunks, which may be under proj1, or under projx/subprojZY  but not the branches.

Answer (score 1):

SVN update will always limit itself to the depth of the checkout done earlier.
So you need to run multiple 'svn checkout' commands (vs `svn update`).

Here's how I would do it:

```
svn checkout $url /workingcopy --depth immediates
```

This gets you all 'projX' folders, without content.

```
for $f in /workingcopy/*; do svn checkout $url/$f /workingcopy/$f" --depth immediates; done
```

This fetches projX/[trunk|tags|branches], also without content.

```
svn checkout $url/proj3/trunk /workingcopy/proj3/trunk
```

This checks out the full content of the trunk folder of proj3.

Comment: getting to believe there's no way besides a 'update script'. you are right